# Get only Password Credential without Prompting the cmdlet Get-Credential in Powershell

Tags: powershell, credentials

How to Validate the Password from your Credential? I was trying to get my account password and set it as a script password. I don't want the cmdlet Get-Credential prompt and I only need the password for the verification. Is that possible?

So far, I have this code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/806868/using-invoke-command-using-credentials-to-run-get.html and just tweaked it a little but obviously it proceeds to the "The Password is Correct" because it Compares the *System.Security.SecureString* as a string. What should I do?

```
    $inputPass = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$env:DOMAIN\$env:USER", $inputPass)

# If the Password is same with the Password of your PC Account.
    if ($inputPass -match $credential.Password) {
         "The Password is Correct"
     } else {
         "Wrong Password, Type-in your Account Password"
         Break;
     }
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you :)

Comment: I believe you want `if ($inputPass -eq $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password) {` and `$env:USER` should most likely be `$env:USERNAME`. But also I'm not sure how this check serves as a password validation

Comment: I also noticed that the $inputPass in $credential is just getting the Password I typed-in, so even if it is wrong it will proceed. It really didn't get my account password, but what should I replace with that?

Comment: If you are trying to test if the network credentials are valid you can do something like what's described on this page https://itpro-tips.com/2019/test-ad-authentication-via-powershell/

Comment: that's the right answer @Daniel, assuming the computer is domain joined, the right validation is against Active Directory. You should post it as answer

Comment: And if you are trying to get logged in password to check against, in short, you can't.

Comment: ooh, does that mean that what I'm trying to do is quite impossible and needs to incorporate with an active directory?

Comment: hmm I see, so there's no way I can get the password of the logged-on user without the cmdlet Get-Credential prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you're looking to validate if the Password inputted via [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.2) is valid for the current user against Active Directory, if so, you can follow the [technique demonstrated in the helpful link provided](https://itpro-tips.com/2019/test-ad-authentication-via-powershell/) by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel) in comments with some slight modification since I'll be using [`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?view=net-6.0) to get the current user Domain and UserName:

```bash
$encrypted = Read-Host "Enter Password" -AsSecureString
$plain     = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $encrypted).Password
if([adsi]::new('', [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name, $plain).PSBase.Name) {
    'password is valid'
}
else {
    'password is invalid'
}
```